# How to run a function in a transaction with MySQL and SQLite?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, transactions

How can a function be run "in a transaction" (see http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions.html#run_in_transaction with MySQL and SQLite? (and other RDBMSs if anyone knows how)?

EDIT: I want to do so in Python, but a way to do it in other programming languages would also be okay.

Comment: SQLite: http://sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on the RDBMS you use, what programming language you're writing in, and what library you use to connect.

With MySQL, you issue a `START TRANSACTION` query before the queries you want to be run in a transaction, and a `COMMIT` query to run that transaction.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

Comment: And with MySQL, _that_ only works when you're using a storage engine that supports transactions (e.g., InnoDB does, MyISAM doesn't).